# Error Code: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '=' error on simple select query

Tags: mysql

I am getting

> #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '='

this error on below query

```
SELECT * FROM 
sm_product_inventories_list 
WHERE  inventory_date =  CURDATE() 
AND  inventory_time =  CURTIME()
```

I tried to change collation of table by

```
ALTER TABLE sm_product_inventories_list CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci
```

still I am getting error.
Type of inventory_date is date and inventory_time is varchar

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does `CAST(inventory_time AS TIME)` work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick solution is to add "binary" before comparing as follows,

`WHERE binary inventory_date = binary CURDATE() AND binary inventory_time =  binary CURTIME()`