# PDO statement generating Illegal mix of collations ERROR. What could generate this error?

Tags: php, mysql, binary

I have the follow piece of code in PHP receiving variables from the browser ($dt_start and $dt_end) querying a MySql database:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblA 
        WHERE  ':dt_start'<=tblA.date AND tblA.date<=':dt_end';";
$dt_start="2018-01-01";//test dt_start
$dt_end="2018-03-30";//test dt_ent future
$this->myDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = $this->myDB->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':dt_start', $dt_start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':dt_end', $dt_end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And this is the error Im getting:

```
Err: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '<='' in /var/www/html/...file.php:4366 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/...file.php(4366): PDOStatement->execute() #1 /var/www/html/files....php(40):
```

However If I use the sql statement without bind variables like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblA 
        WHERE  '2018-01-01'<=tblA.date AND tblA.date<='2018-03-30';";
$this->myDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = $this->myDB->prepare($sql);
#$query->bindParam(':dt_start', $dt_start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
#$query->bindParam(':dt_end', $dt_end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It works and I find 200 results.

After this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43368771/error-code-1267-illegal-mix-of-collations-utf8-general-ci-implicit-and-latin?rq=1) I found that we can use binary, like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tblA 
        WHERE  ':dt_start'<= binary tblA.date AND binary tblA.date<=':dt_end';";
$dt_start="2018-01-01";
$dt_end="2018-03-30";
$this->myDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$query = $this->myDB->prepare($sql);
$query->bindParam(':dt_start', $dt_start, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->bindParam(':dt_end', $dt_end, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();
$data = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now I have no erros however I have no results, 0 results. Nothing was found.

The conclusion:

1. If I use the date directly in the query it works -> find 200 results.
2. If I use bind PDO throw 1267 Illegal mix of collations
3. If I use binary in the query, have no error and find 0 results.

What is happening here?

Comment: is altering the table and converting character sets out of the question?

Comment: yes out of question, specially sets. I want to understanding what is happening before to go to this extreme solution.